# How to apply SETs properties in this example?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $$ A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
and $$ B=\{1,2,3,6,7\}$$
and $$ C=\{1,2,3,8,9\}$$

is it correct to state:
$$(A \cup B)-C = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}-\{1,2,3,8,9\}=\{4,5,6,7\}$$
$$A \cup (B-C) = \{1,2,3,4,5\} \cup \{6,7\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$$
hence $$(A \cup B)-C\neq A \cup (B-C)$$

Comment: Everything looks ok to me.

Comment: @Shay: To show set braces, you need \{ and \}

Comment: If you were merely trying to prove that there exist sets $A,B,C$ such that $(A\cup B)\setminus C \neq A\cup (B\setminus C)$, then you could have done this using much smaller sets.  In particular with $A=B=C=\{1\}$ this is sufficient to disprove the proposed identity.  There would be no reason to use sets with so many elements to do this.